# FastReport for Blazor not seeing .Web namespace

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, blazor, fastreport

I am trying the FastReport demo for Blazor: [FastReport Blazor](https://www.fast-report.com/public_download/docs/FRNet/online/en/ProgrammerManual/en-US/Blazor/Preflight.html)

But after following all of the steps exactly I get the following message: "The type name 'Web' does not exist in the type 'FastReport'".

I also tried by directly adding the .dll files through VS but that doesn't seem to make a difference. Sadly since I am trying the demo/free trial I cannot get support from FastReport.

Answer (score 1):

You might have install the wrong package. For this demo https://github.com/FastReports/FastReport.Blazor.Demo, you needn't install anything on your own, just run it directly will be fine.
The csproj seems not reference an official version.
[image]

Make sure you have the correct version installed.
[image]
[image]

Comment: So I can't add the trial version to my own Blazor project? Because I have noticed the FastReports controlls are not working in Winforms either. So it just seems like the Trial blocks adding anything to your custom project.

Comment: @parrotmaster emmm, I am not sure. At least it doesn't block you to add things to their demo project.

Comment: Sadly I couldn't get this to work (at least within reasonable effort given) so I have decided to drop it for now. Sadly that also means I couldn't confirm your answer was correct so I'll have to leave it with only an upvote.